# Find $\frac{{dy(0)}}{{dx}}$ for $x \ge 0$, where, $y = Q(\sqrt x )$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, convex-optimization, limits-without-lhopital

$Q(\sqrt x )$ is a decreasing function for $x\ge0$ where,

$Q(x) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int\limits_x^\infty  {{{\mathop{\rm e}\nolimits} ^{ - \frac{{{u^2}}}{2}}}du}$

The derivative of the function is

$\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} =  - \frac{{{e^{ - \frac{x}{4}}}}}{{4\sqrt {\pi x} }}$.

Is is possible to find $\frac{{dy(0)}}{{dx}}$? I think this should exist ( it exists for $x \to {0_ + }$ but I dont know how to show that). Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Write, for $h>0$,
$$
\frac{y(h)-y(0)}{h}=-\frac{1}{h\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\sqrt{h} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du=-\frac{e^{-\frac{c^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2h\pi}}
$$
where $0<c<h$ by the Mean Value Theorem for integrals.

Letting $h\to 0^+$, we get that the limit does not exist.

Comment: I apologize. But can I do it from the derivative expression, where $\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} =  - \frac{{{e^{ - \frac{x}{4}}}}}{{4\sqrt {\pi x} }}$. Can we do $h \to 0$ for this case?

Comment: @hasan I had made a mistake, forgot the square root. The function is not differentiable at $0$. In particular, using the expression of $y'$ for $x>0$ is not legitimate.

Comment: And my function is $Q(sqrt(x))$. Does the result will be same for $Q(x)$. Thank you.

Comment: @hasan For $Q(x)$, what I had written before shows that it differentiable at $0$. Still, this needs to be checked using the definition of the derivative.

Comment: @hasan Can you comment, please, how you obtain formula for derivative?

Comment: @hasan I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I know that $Q(x) = \frac{1}{2}erfc(x/\sqrt 2 )$;  then by putting $x=\sqrt x $ we can write,  $Q(\sqrt x ) = \frac{1}{2}erfc(\sqrt x /\sqrt 2 )$. From wolphramAlpha website I got the derivative of $erfc(\sqrt(x))$. Am I right? or I did some big mistake. Thank you.

Comment: $Q=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} erfc$, if  $erfc$   you take from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html    no?

Comment: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/0470024135.app6 I got the relation of Gaussian $Q$ function and $erfc$ relation from that link I mention in this comment. And yes you are right. The $erfc$ i took from in this website that you mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: So, do you agree, that derivative is $\dfrac{dQ}{dx} = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-x^2}$  ?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. But my function is $\frac{{dQ(\sqrt x )}}{{dx}} =  - \frac{{{e^{ - \frac{x}{4}}}}}{{4\sqrt {\pi x} }}$. Am I right? And is it possible to take the limit at zero here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let me denote $$f(x) = \int_{x}^{+ \infty}e^{-t^2}dt = \left(\int_{0}^{+ \infty}-\int_{0}^{x} \right)e^{-t^2}dt$$
For derivative we have $f^{'}(x) = -e^{-x^2} \rightarrow -1$, when $x \rightarrow 0$.

Then, let's consider definition of derivative in $x=0$:
$$\dfrac{1}{x} \cdot (f(x)-f(0))=-\dfrac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt = - e^{-c(x)^2} $$
where $0 \leqslant c(x)\leqslant x $. This gives $f^{'}(0)$ = -1 and coincides with limit of $f^{'}(x)$.

$$Q(x) =\frac{1}{\sqrt {2 \pi }} \int_{x}^{+ \infty}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du =\frac{1}{\sqrt {2 \pi }} \int_{\sqrt{2}x}^{+ \infty}e^{-u^2}du = \frac{1}{\sqrt {2 \pi }} f(\sqrt{2}x)$$

Comment: Is it valid for $Q(\sqrt x)$?

Comment: Added last line for  $Q$ and $f$ connection.

Comment: I apologize. I did not understand the connection to take the limit at $x=0$ for  $\frac{{dQ(\sqrt x )}}{{dx}}$. Because for this case $\sqrt(x)$ appears in the denominator of the derivative of .${Q(\sqrt x )}$.

Comment: So answer you had choose is correct?

Comment: Yes. I think for $Q(\sqrt x)$ the derivative at zero does not exists.